# Regex to match event ID (Less greedy)

Tags: java, regex

I wrote a basic Regex to match any of the specific event ID's 4727|4731|4759|4744|4749

The problem that I am having is that it is matching a pattern found in a non-standard event that is more than 4 characters.

EventID=21**4749**8949

What is the best way of writing the Regex so that it will only match on the 5 specific events and ignore anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few way you could work this out.

If EventID= is constantly there, like so:

- EventID=2147498949
- EventID=4731

You could always go for something like this:

```
EventID=(4727|4731|4759|4744|4749)$
```

- `$` The end of the string

But otherwhise, you could go with something of the sort:

```
\b(4727|4731|4759|4744|4749)\b
```

- `\b` Is a  word boundary

[Here's an example](https://regex101.com/r/ytNy7x/3)

Which would say that there should be a word boundary before and after the string of 4 digits your looking for.

Comment: But what about the case he describes where the full ID is something like `2147498949`? This will not match

Comment: From my understanding, the problem the OP was facing was that it did match that even't number, which he didn't want to do:"The problem that I am having is that it is matching a pattern found in a non-standard"

Comment: Ah, yep. I think you're right. I may have mis-read it. My mistake

Comment: `\D(4727|4731|4759|4744|4749)\D` doesn't match `"EventID=4731"`. `\b` would work, though.

Comment: You're right, thank you. I've added a link to an example with regex101, that should also allow the OP to test with some of his/her own code.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @TaoStyle's answer

> ```
> =(4727|4731|4759|4744|4749)$
> ```

This will only work if you add the multi-line flag:

```
/=(4727|4731|4759|4744|4749)$/m
```

**Suggestion:** If you want more IDs later with exactly 4 digits, why don't you use`/=\d{4}/m`?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a word boundary (`\b`). Check it out:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(4727|4731|4759|4744|4749)\\b");
    for (String in : new String[]{"EventID=2147498949", "EventID=4727"}) {
        System.out.println(pattern.matcher(in).find());
    }
```

Also if your pattern always starts from `EventID=` it's a good idea to include it into pattern and use [group capturing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg)